# Assume that $|x| = mn$, where $\gcd(m, n) = 1$. Show that there exists $y, z \in G$ such that $x = yz = zy$, $|y| = m$ and $|z| = n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Sea $G$ un grupo y $x \in G$. Asuma que $\vert x \vert  = mn$, donde $\gcd(m, n) = 1$. Demuestre que existe $y, z \in G$, tal
que $x = yz = zy$, $\vert y \vert  = m$ y $\vert z\vert  = n.$

Translation:

Let $G$ be a group and $x \in G$. Assume that $\vert x \vert  = mn$, where $\gcd(m, n) = 1$. Show that there exists $y, z \in G$ such that $x = yz = zy$, $\vert y \vert  = m$ and $\vert z\vert  = n.$

Comment: Presumo che tu abbia fatto qualcosa.

Comment: @Gae.S. The OP wrote in Spanish, not in Italian.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos How can I not have noticed that?

Comment: What does $|x|$ mean when $x$ is an element of a general group?

Comment: @saulspatz $|x|$ is the order of $x$.

Comment: @cxx Thank you.

Comment: If this is true in any group $G$, it must be true in the cyclic subgroup generated by $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\gcd(n, m) = 1$, then there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that $an + bm = 1$. What happens when we let $y = x^{an}$ and $z = x^{bm}$?